# Unable to call api.backblaze.com out of jboss

Tags: java, ssl, jboss, backblaze

I am trying to upload an image to backblaze online storage. I use the backblaze java-sdk to make the call. When trying to upload an image I get the following error:

```
2020-04-25 11:19:45,443 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10) <B2Exception 904 io_exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target talking to https://api.backblazeb2.com/b2api/v2/b2_authorize_account>
```

I could not find any information about the necessary of adding any certificates on the backblaze site.

After some research on the internet, I found out that I should? add the backblaze certificate to the trust store of my java installation. So I downloaded the certificate using chrome (saved as .cer file) from https://www.backblaze.com/ and installed it to my java with this command:

```
keytool -import -alias backblaze -keystore "%JAVA_HOME%/jre/lib/security/cacerts" -storepass <password> -keypass changeit -file .../backblaze.cer -noprompt
```

I also can see it when executing this command:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore "%JAVA_HOME%/jre/lib/security/cacerts"
```

There is an entry with alias: backblaze

Using the VM option `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl` during my jboss startup I can see that java uses the correct trust store and find an entry with backblaze alias:

```
2020-04-25 10:46:52,483 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2) trustStore is: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\jre\lib\security\cacerts
2020-04-25 10:46:52,483 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2) trustStore type is : jks
2020-04-25 10:46:52,483 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2) trustStore provider is : 
2020-04-25 10:46:52,484 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2) init truststore
...
2020-04-25 10:46:52,564 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2) adding as trusted cert:
2020-04-25 10:46:52,739 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2)   Subject: CN=backblaze.com, O="Backblaze, Inc.", L=San Mateo, ST=California, C=US, SERIALNUMBER=4337553, OID.1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.2=Delaware, OID.1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.3=US, OID.2.5.4.15=Private Organization
2020-04-25 10:46:52,739 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2)   Issuer:  CN=DigiCert SHA2 Extended Validation Server CA, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
...
```

So I think the java process could find the correct certificate, but when I cann the api.backblaze endpoint I get the exception with the handhake:

```
2020-04-25 11:19:45,443 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10) <B2Exception 904 io_exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target talking to https://api.backblazeb2.com/b2api/v2/b2_authorize_account>

2020-04-25 11:19:45,444 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)    at com.backblaze.b2.client.webApiHttpClient.B2WebApiHttpClientImpl.translateToB2Exception(B2WebApiHttpClientImpl.java:256)

2020-04-25 11:19:45,445 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)    at com.backblaze.b2.client.webApiHttpClient.B2WebApiHttpClientImpl.postAndReturnString(B2WebApiHttpClientImpl.java:223)

2020-04-25 11:19:45,445 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)    at com.backblaze.b2.client.webApiHttpClient.B2WebApiHttpClientImpl.postJsonAndReturnString(B2WebApiHttpClientImpl.java:185)

2020-04-25 11:19:45,445 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)    at com.backblaze.b2.client.webApiHttpClient.B2WebApiHttpClientImpl.postJsonReturnJson(B2WebApiHttpClientImpl.java:71)

2020-04-25 11:19:45,445 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)    at com.backblaze.b2.client.B2StorageClientWebifierImpl.authorizeAccount(B2StorageClientWebifierImpl.java:141)

2020-04-25 11:19:45,445 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)    at com.backblaze.b2.client.B2AccountAuthorizerSimpleImpl.authorize(B2AccountAuthorizerSimpleImpl.java:38)

2020-04-25 11:19:45,446 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)    at com.backblaze.b2.client.B2AccountAuthorizationCache.get(B2AccountAuthorizationCache.java:50)

2020-04-25 11:19:45,446 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)    at com.backblaze.b2.client.B2UploadUrlCache.get(B2UploadUrlCache.java:87)

2020-04-25 11:19:45,446 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)    at com.backblaze.b2.client.B2StorageClientImpl.lambda$uploadSmallFile$4(B2StorageClientImpl.java:207)

2020-04-25 11:19:45,446 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)    at com.backblaze.b2.client.B2Retryer.doRetry(B2Retryer.java:85)

2020-04-25 11:19:45,446 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)    at com.backblaze.b2.client.B2StorageClientImpl.uploadSmallFile(B2StorageClientImpl.java:204)
```

I am new to SSL and I don't understand what I am doing wrong. Either I downloaded the wrong certificate (and api.backblaze has got an extra certificate which I have to install) or I configured my java trust store wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after some struggling around I found out that I used the wrong vertificate. I had to download the certificate from api.backblazeb2.com and install it:

Download:

```
keytool -printcert -sslserver api.backblazeb2.com:443 -rfc > api.backblazeb2.cer
```

Install:

```
keytool -import -alias api.backblazeb2 -keystore "%JAVA_HOME%/jre/lib/security/cacerts" -storepass changeit -keypass changeit -file api.backblazeb2.cer -nopro
mpt
```

To be sure restart your java process after that.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and don't trust the individual certificate for backblaze directly. That one expires May 25, 2020. It's issuer, Let's Encrypt Authority X3, expires a bit later, March 17, 2021, but is an intermediate CA. You generally should only trust selected trust anchors, and in this case, trust DST Root CA X3. While that one expires only a bit later, September 30, 2021, it's good practice to trust trust anchors and not intermediate CAs. They are called trust anchors and are installed by default for a reason!